# Assign same text to multiple DIV by jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose that I have many `DIV`s with different `ID`s and I want to insert a small snippet of html into all of those `DIV`s with different `ID`s. I tried

```
$("#lblTopPager", "#lblBottomPager").html('hello my data');
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the correct way to do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements need to be a comma seperated list, right now you are giving context, and basically looking for an element with the ID `lblTopPager` inside the element with ID `lblBottomPager`, just as if you where using `$('#lblBottomPager').find('#lblTopPager')`.

To target two or more elements at the same time you could do :

```
$("#lblTopPager, #lblBottomPager").html('hello my data');
```

Comment: can i here use wild card because few part is fixed. can write this line like $("input[id*='lblTopPager'],input[id*='lblBottomPager']). this is lblTopPager span basically

Comment: `$("input[id*='lblTopPager'], input[id*='lblBottomPager']")` should work!